# Open application on mobile from html link

Tags: html

I have a html page with my social media accounts, and i want when i click those links to go to my profile on those social media app.
for example Skype:

```
<a href="skype:live:my_skype_email" > My Skype </a>
```

when i'm on mobile and i click on this link it open skype and go to my account.
i want to do the same thing with facebook, twitter, google+, instagram, whatsapp, kik, snapchat. 
i want something like this

```
<a href="my_facebook_username" > Facebook </a>
<a href="my_twitter_username" > twitter </a>
<a href="my_googleplus_username" > google+ </a>
<a href="my_instagrame_username" > instagram </a>
<a href="my_whatsapp_number" > whatsapp </a>
<a href="my_kik_username" > kik </a>
<a href="my_snapcchat_username" > snapchat </a>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to find out if those apps install a protocol handler and if yes, what is it called.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find the protocol handler that each app provider uses (if they support it). As an example, you can launch the Twitter app with a link through the following:

```
<a href="twitter://user?screen_name=ler">Twitter</a>
```

Hope that helps - from a quick Google, it looks like all of the apps you listed support this.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use this pattern for the href attibutes:

```
"appname://"
```

For example:

```
<a href="fb://profile/fbID">Facebook</a>
<a href="twitter://user?screen_name=username">Twitter</a>
```

This will open the application on a mobile when it is installed.