# Rundeck output as clickable link

Tags: rundeck, vcenter

Does anyone know if there is a way to have the output of an executed job be a clickable link?

I have a script that gets a link for a virtual environment in vCenter via powercli and I wanted to simplify the process in which the user got the vmdk console brought up. They currently have to select->copy->paste to search bar for it to work.

Here is my script:

```
Echo "Your Virtual Machine is now created and is being retrieved now."
$vcenter_password= "@option.vcenter_password@"
$Template_Name= "@option.Template_Name@"
if(-not (Get-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -ListAvailable)){
Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -AllowClobber -Force -Confirm:$false
}
Connect-VIServer -Server {{vcenter}} -User Administrator@DEPLOY.COMMS -Password $vcenter_password -Force
Get-VM $Template_Name | Select-Object @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[0])}}
Echo "Your VM is available at the following URL for the next 30 seconds:"
Open-VMConsoleWindow -VM "$Template_Name" -urlonly
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app supports HTML links like `appname://`, you can generate an HTML [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) output in your Rundeck job. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40978401/10426011).